# Let user change ordering of a ManyToManyField in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

My models are something like following:

```
class Reading(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=250)
    url = models.URLField()

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    readings = models.ManyToManyField(Reading)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The ordering of Reading(these are just blog posts) in Lessons matters. This can be done by meta class options *order_with_respect_to*. But I want that a user(creator of that Lesson) can change the ordering of the Reading in a Lesson. How can I do this?

One way I thought about this is, I should create a ForeignKey of Lesson from 
Reading model and have one more field called ordering with IntegerField, which a User editing that can change. Is this right approach?

Also I found that this is same as saying a User having a todo list and should have ability to change the ordering of tasks he want to do.

Comment: will each user have their own order, or is each user changing a variable on the a lesson object (such that their new order will be seen by other users)?

Comment: No every user will see same order. A creator of that Lesson can change the order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `through` model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany